# How would you make a simple cipher for an integer in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I have an integer output from a private controller action that I would like to store 'encrypted' in my database. What methods would you use to codify this integer such that I can retrieve up to ~200 of these numbers easily and quickly to be served in a view to the right user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://github.com/spikex/strongbox

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a SHA1 hash? Or a flagmap? Or what is 'encrypted' exactly?

Comment: I'm new to this so I regret I don't yet know what SHA1 hash or flagmap means :). I would like to mask the numbers' true identity in the system, so that the only way to retrieve the data in a meaningful way is to be in possession of the controller method. This method performs calculations and outputs a decimal from ~0-15, which I would then like to translate into 'meaningless' data for the database.